# The fear of not seeing one's mother ever again

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, obscure-terms, phobias

Is there a word to describe the fear of never again seeing one's mother (or at least any person)?

I have already checked the list of phobias that Wikipedia offers but could not find anything that fits the specific meaning I am looking for; perhaps there is such a word, but it does not have the word *phobia* attached to it.

Thanks.

Comment: If the person with the fear is a young child and the potential lost object over whom the fear arises is the child's mother, the psychological term often used for it is "separation anxiety."

Answer (score 4):

Is "[separation anxiety disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_anxiety_disorder)" the expression you're looking for?

> *SAD (Separation Anxiety Disorder) is a condition in which an individual experiments excessive anxiety regarding separation from home or from people to whom the individual has a strong emotional attachment, i.e. a parent, grandparents, or siblings.*

Answer (score 0):

The ***fear of not seeing one's mother ever again*** also refers to the ***fear of death or*** ***dead things*** and is called **NECROPHOBIA**.

Comment: You might want to provide a link or a reference for this so the users can go check this information.